# UniFi Network Controlled Devices Disconnected No UniFi Security Gateway detected

Tags: unifi

Having an issue where my devices show as disconnected after doing a cleanup setup of a UniFi Security Gateway, switch, and access point in my home network.

[image]

The controller also shows that the UniFi Security Gateway is not detected. The devices where all working fine before, but now my internet connection on all of the devices on my home network drop sometimes. Even the wired connections have this behavior. I think running an upgrade could resolve issue with my internet connection dropping, but I am unable to manage my devices in the UniFi portal.

I also tried to ssh into my UniFi Security Gateway and reboot from the command line, that also did not resolve my issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately one possible solution that applied to me was documented under the [Device doesn't appear for adoption section of the UniFi FAQ](https://help.ui.com/hc/en-us/articles/360012622613). Curious to see what feedback others have as I'd like to find another way around this issue without turning off my firewall.

> 3. Temporarily disable firewall and antivirus software After the issue is resolved, you can create a firewall exception to ensure the devices
>    work without disabling the firewall completely.